# Spring Boot JNDI resource-ref

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I need to declare a resource-ref in a Spring Boot application that will be deployed as war file. This is needed in order to access the database. In traditional webapps, this is added to the web.xml. How can I achieve this in a Spring Boot way?

Thanks,
Benjamin

Comment: Here - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource.

Comment: Yep, but I asked for the resource-ref.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I didn't see that. May be you need to declare bean of type `org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource`. There should be a direct option for configuration though.

Comment: You don't need a resource-ref you can directly use a `JndiDataSourceLookup` to do a lookup for the JNDI resource.

Comment: This might work on appservers like jBoss where the naming Tree is public accessible, but on others you need to declare a resource-ref to make the appserver aware that you gonna access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We got that resolved a while back, so I thought, I'd post this here.

---

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DefaultDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

---

src/main/resources/application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jndi-name: jdbc/DefaultDB
```

---

src/main/java//DataSourceConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean // optional
    public DataSource jndiDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        return (DataSource) context.lookup("unmanageddatasource:" + properties.getJndiName());
    }
}
```

Comment: HI @Benny 

with this bean definition, how would I go about getting the reference to the datasource - previously I would 
`DataSource dataSource = null;
  JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
  try {
   dataSource = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB");
  } catch (NamingException e) {
   logger.error("NamingException for java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB", e);
  }
  return dataSource;`