# Spring Boot still requires resource-ref in web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

Looking into Spring Boot right now and want to do it properly, as using Java config and ultimately without any `web.xml`. So, the tricky part is that the production environment requires a classic `WAR` file.

Hence, I'm specified `WAR` packaging within my Maven `pom.xml`file and the main Application class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

Works just fine. Now, the tricky part is that in the production environment the `Datasource` is provisioned via `JNDI`. In a classic Spring app you would reference this dependency in the `web.xml` using a `resource-ref` as follows:

```
 <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DefaultDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

All the research I did seems to indicate that I would be able to get rid of the `web.xml` and replacing it with a respective `context.xml` file (in META-INF folder):

```
   <Resource name="jdbc/DefaultDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="com.sap.jpaas.service.persistence.core.JNDIDataSourceFactory"/>
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work :/

The interesting thing though is that a plain servlet3 web app works just fine that way, see [https://github.com/steinermatt/servlet3-sample].

So, I'm tempted to believe that the root cause it doesn't work for a Spring Boot app is related to the Spring Boot bootstrapping process... so, really looking for any hints, suggestions on what it could be!!!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The solution given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56663753/2163693 may be useful to people who come across this thread...it worked for me specifically for this SCP neo scenario

Comment: Did you ever find a solution Mattias? Ian - how did you use the solution in the linked answer?

Answer (score 0):

By default, JNDI is disabled in embedded Tomcat.

You could use following code to enable JNDI in tomcat. Following code will help you initialize DataSource spring bean.

```
    @Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("jdbc/myDataSource");
            resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "your.db.Driver");
            resource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:yourDb");

            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
        }
    };
}
```

You could use DataSource bean in your controller using auto-wiring.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```